# Is there a way to see preexisting relationships in a database?

Tags: microsoft-access, dependencies

I'm using MS Access 2007 and working on cleaning up a functioning database.

I want to see the relationships between the tables and queries at will, but the closest I can get is the object dependencies panel. This is insufficient.

Is there a clearer way to identify what is connected to what in this database?

I should also note that I'm a database beginner, so I'm unfamiliar with SQL as I've just really used Access windows and buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access has no built in way to show all the dependancies that you need. In particular, it can display the foreign key relationships between tables (though not all databases have this made already; you may need to run a wizard to generate the dependancy map). But I'm not aware of any tool that lists all the tables and queries that other objects like queries and forms depend on.

I suspect you may have to create this manually.